# How do i disable URL encoding using retrofit2 with Okhttp3

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a simple Google Places Query string from https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search.

The following URL shows a search for restaurants near Sydney.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

But then my retrofit2 & Okhttp3 encodes it like this below:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants%2Bin%2BSydney&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Replacing every occurrence of **"+"** with **"%2B"**. And i wish to stop this.

How do I achieve this please?

**Edit**

I just finished reading the Github issue https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1407 , No answer found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does this work for you ?

```
Call<List<Articles>> getArticles((@QueryMap(encoded=true) Map<String, String> options);
```

encoded =true should tell retrofit that the paramter is already encoded.